# Changing the content in the anychart loader

Tags: html, css, anychart

I am trying to show some text in anychart loader method instead of the default columns red,orange,green. I have created new .css file using (https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/css/anychart-ui.min.css) as suggested in the example and tried to change the loader portion with text and image but could see the changes, I want to show text or image (Eg:-loading..) instead of default columns.Can anyone tell me how can i make the changes in the Anychart loader.

Comment: okay..I have done it using the class in css and using jquery and it  works.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible via API, but we can offer you to work with the CSS directly, e.g.

```
document.getElementsByClassName(' anychart-loader-rotating-cover')[0].innerHTML = 'Loading...';
```

See the full sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/eo0a6cmf/

Comment: Yeah, I have done it using jquery It worked-->                                             
   $('.anychart-loader-rotating-plane').html("Loading...");